# SOAPUI Not Showing Operations from WSDL

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl, soapui, svcutil.exe

I am struggling to get SOAPUI to show my operations in my service, I generate my WSDL from exposed MEX endpoints (So not manual) then I create my CLIENT proxies from the generated WSDL. From a code perspective this works fine (My unit tests pass if the host is running and fail if it is down).

I would like to use SOAPUI to do some low level testing but if I consume that same WSDL used to generate the proxies then it does not show any operations (Even though the WSDL is working)

**Generate WSDL**
svcutil /target:metadata "net.tcp://localhost:10109/AnimalService"

**Generate Proxies**
svcutil /t:code ..*.wsdl ..*.xsd /out:Proxy.cs /config:Proxy.config

I assume I am doing something wrong, any help will be appreciated.

The Primary WSDL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:i0="http://spikes/WcfCodeFirstExample/services/AnimalService" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" name="AnimalService" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:import namespace="http://spikes/WcfCodeFirstExample/services/AnimalService" location="" />
  <wsdl:types />
  <wsdl:service name="AnimalService">
    <wsdl:port name="NetTCPBinding_IAnimalService" binding="i0:NetTCPBinding_IAnimalService">
      <soap12:address location="net.tcp://localhost:10109/AnimalService.svc" />
      <wsa10:EndpointReference>
        <wsa10:Address>net.tcp://localhost:10109/AnimalService.svc</wsa10:Address>
      </wsa10:EndpointReference>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

The Secondary WSDL (Referenced in First)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:i0="Spike.Contracts.Services" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="http://spikes/WcfCodeFirstExample/services/AnimalService" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" targetNamespace="http://spikes/WcfCodeFirstExample/services/AnimalService" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="NetTCPBinding_IAnimalService_policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
      <wsp:All>
        <msb:BinaryEncoding xmlns:msb="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/06/2004/mspolicy/netbinary1"></msb:BinaryEncoding>
        <wsaw:UsingAddressing></wsaw:UsingAddressing>
      </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
  </wsp:Policy>
  <wsdl:import namespace="Spike.Contracts.Services" location="" />
  <wsdl:types />
  <wsdl:binding name="NetTCPBinding_IAnimalService" type="i0:IAnimalService">
    <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#NetTCPBinding_IAnimalService_policy"></wsp:PolicyReference>
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.microsoft.com/soap/tcp" />
    <wsdl:operation name="GetAvailableAnimalTypes">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="Spike.Contracts.Services/IAnimalService/GetAvailableAnimalTypes" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="AddPetAnimalType">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="Spike.Contracts.Services/IAnimalService/AddPetAnimalType" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Please keep in mind this is generated WSDL and XSD's not hand rolled. I tried with both a netTcpbinding and basicHttpBinding configuration. It very well might be that I am using SOAPUI incorrectly but if I try the sample WSDL (http://www.webservicex.com/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?wsdl) I do see the associated operations so I assume I am doing it right.

[image]

I am using SOAPUI 5.0.

Comment: were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: No, I settled for integration unit tests to test my operations (Dropped SOAP UI as my testing suite). This won't always be possible/feasible so need to get SOAP UI working at some point.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this exact same issue and it turns out I was using `WebHttpBinding` instead of `BasicHttpBinding`. Once I switched to using `BasicHttpBinding` all the operations/methods were showing up in SoapUI.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: @ed22 It should be in the config file where you are configuring your wcf service endpoints.  If you are not using configuration then in the code you would be using the `BasicHttpBinding` class instead of `WebHttpBinding`.   `BasicHttpBinding` = SOAP and `WebHttpBinding` = REST so you have to be using both REST or SOAP in SOAPUI and your wcf service for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still looking at this 6 yrs later like I was.  In my case I had several WebMethod calls that showed but a new WebMethod would not show.  Ran update several times & while SoapUI said that it updated 133 methods, the new method still didn't show.

For me the fix was to delete the existing definition and then add a new definition instead of updating the existing & then the new method showed in the new defintion.  A simple solution but not sure why update didn't work.